# What happened to "The Greek" in the Wire?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wire

"The Greek" managed to board a plane with Vondas at the end of season 2 therefore avoiding being arrested.

I remember a scene in season 5 where Marlo meets Vondas on a park bench which leads to a deal between the two and cutting out proposition Joe.

Was the Greek ever mentioned or seen again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He's at the bar in the final episode when the Co-op members meet with Vondas to arrange their deal.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing happens to the Greek or to Vondas, which exemplifies one of the major themes of the series: True change is impossible to enact. You can replace the moving parts or force them to hide for a while, but the game is always the game.